# Apache Pig: Guice creation errors. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to write a Pig script that uses my UDF. When I run it, I run into ‘Guice creation errors’ such as ‘java.lang.NoSuchMethodError’. Clearly, my hadoop environment is using a different version of Guice than I am using. I tried several ways of **putting my Jar in front**, such as:

1. REGISTER my.jar
2. Add it to **front of** ‘PIG_CLASSPATH’, ‘HADOOP_CLASSPATH’, ‘CLASSPATH’.
3. Tried: export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
4. -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true

None of these worked! Version # of Hadoop: **Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.5**

Here’s my simple script:

```
REGISTER my.jar;
A = LOAD '/tmp/mydir/' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A generate com.mypackage.udf.MyUdf(line);
dump B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either provide the absolution path while REGISTER the udf.jar

OR

provided the jar using additional jar command.

> pig **-Dpig.additional.jars=/absolute/path/of/jar/my.jar** [your_other_paramter]

Also you can define a name of your UDF, at top of the script, so that you don't have to provide complete UDF name each time.

```
REGISTER /absolute/path/of/my.jar;
define MyUDF com.mypackage.udf.MyUdf(line)
A = LOAD '/tmp/mydir/' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A MyUDF(line);
dump B;
```

Comment: Did not work. What's the equivalent of -libjars in Pig?